# Counting for each grouped value within 'with' (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm building a query that is counting certain subgroups using several `with` statements. The final subquery that I'm having trouble with is the summation of the total amount of possible customers. I'm creating a sample that's a little more simplistic than what I'm really building, so bear with the sample.

Basically the end result should look like this:

[image]

Note that it isn't as simple as just adding the two columns together to get the total. In this case, the customers can, for example, leave the organization and then they wouldn't be counted in the total possible customers.  There is a column that indicates when a customer enters that pool and another where the customer leaves. So I need something to do a count on each given month that takes that into consideration. (Basically a `select count(*) from customers where entry_date < [month being evaluated] and leave date !< [month being evaluated]`). This is where my problem comes in, so this is what I have so far:

```
WITH customer_type1 AS 
(
    SELECT c1_visit_date, COUNT(*) AS c1_count
    FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(c.visit_time, 'MON YYYY') AS c1_visit_date
    FROM customer c
    where customer_type='1')
    GROUP BY c1_visit_date;
),
customer_type2 AS 
(
    SELECT c2_visit_date, COUNT(*) as c2_count    
    FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(c.visit_time, 'MON YYYY') AS c2_visit_date
    FROM customer c
    where customer_type='2')
    GROUP BY c2_visit_date;
),
all_possible_customers AS
(
    SELECT TO_DATE(customer_type1.c1_visit_date) AS APC_Date,
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(c.customer_id)
        FROM customer c
        WHERE customer.start_date < APC_Date
        AND (customer.end_date = NULL OR customer.end_date > APC_Date)
    ) AS all_possible_customer_count
    FROM customer_type1;
)

SELECT customer_type1.c1_visit_date, customer_type1.c1_count, customer_type2.c2_count, all_possible_customers.all_possible_customer_count
FROM customer_type1
INNER JOIN customer_type1 ON customer_type1.c1_visit_date = customer_type2.c2_visit_date
INNER JOIN cusomter_type1 ON customer_type1.c1_visit_date = all_possible_customers.APC date;
```

But I keep running into syntax errors on the third `with` statement. (When I clean it up and run just the first two with statements that get me C.Type1_visit and C.Type2_Visit, they work fine.

What am I missing in this third statement that would allow me to group the select statement by the first column?

Comment: The query inside the third CTE has no `FROM` clause. It essentially is `select to_date(), (..)` - that is invalid. Also `!<` is an invalid operator in SQL. Did you mean to write `<>` ("not equal")?

Comment: Good catch, I actually do have a from in my query, and I updated to reflect what I have.  I missed it when I copied over.

The !< means not less than in SQL Server, but evidently it doesn't exist in Oracle (seems like it isn't ISO).

Comment: In addition to what our nameless equine friend has already mentioned, there are problems across the rest of your entire query - the brackets are misplaced in the first two subqueries, there's no from clause in the final outer query, etc etc. It would benefit you more if you could provide a complete test case that demonstrates what you have and what you want to see (i.e. sample data, expected output data - and not as a picture!) and what you've tried so far as a working, runnable query!

Comment: Isn't `!<` is same as `>=` ? Anyway, your main query is also missing the FROM clause. Presumably that's also not the syntax error you want us to spot.

Comment: Ahh geeze.  Yeah, I didn't want to post the original so I tried to clean it up and change it to a more generic example.  I thought I did a better job than that. I'll double check to make sure my logic is all the same as my original query.  Thanks for the quick responses, this is brutal!!

Comment: If `!<` means `not less than` then in Oracle your predicate should either be `NOT customer.end_date < APC_Date` or `customer.end_date >= APC_Date`; you've accidentally double-negatived things there! Also, we're not trying to be brutal, we're trying to help you, but it's difficult seeing as we can't see your data, database structures and have only what you say to tell us what your requirements are. By giving us a set of sample data, the expected output data based on that sample data and the logic to get from one to the other, you will help us to be able to help you.

Comment: No worries!  I meant brutal ONLY in the sense that I'm rustier on SQL than I had thought. Haven't had to use it for a few years really.

I think I fixed the !< conditional by making it either greater than the current date or having the value be NULL.  

Let me see what I can give for sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the query you've posted, I *think* this is what you're after:

```
SELECT TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm') visit_date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN customer_type = '1' THEN 1 END) c1_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN customer_type = '2' THEN 1 END) c2_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN start_date < TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm') AND (end_date is null or end_date > TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm')) THEN 1 end) all_possible_customer_count
FROM   customer
GROUP BY TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm');
```

However, without sample input and expected output data to test with, it's hard to say whether that's anywhere near what you're after.

I'm a little curious about the logic around your "all possible customer count" - can a customer have a visit date that's outside of the cusutomer's start and end dates? Also, what if the customer's start and end dates were, say, 2nd - 20th March 2017? They wouldn't be counted in the all_possible_customer_count as 1st March is not inside that range.

---

ETA, upon thinking about it, I'm surprised that your requirement isn't something more like "over a given date range, find the count of customers of type 1, type 2 and any type who visited within that range", which would be something like:

```
SELECT TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm') visit_date,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN customer_type = '1' THEN 1 END) c1_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN customer_type = '2' THEN 1 END) c2_count,
       COUNT(*) all_possible_customer_count
FROM   customer
where  start_date <= :end_of_date_range
and    end_date >= :start_of_date_range
GROUP BY TRUNC(visit_date, 'mm');
```

Possibly, with an extra predicate of `and visit_date between start_date and end_date` (assuming no time elements in the dates).

Comment: With these data, they *shouldn't* have have a visit date outside of those dates but it isn't the cleanest set of data. As far as the dates, thats also a good point although it'll be a really small number compared to the overall count (which will actually be in the 10s of thousands). I just got pulled into a meeting in a few minutes but I'll give that a shot when I get back from it.  Thanks for the input so far!

Comment: I've added an extra thought on your requirement and what it might mean for the query; that may be right or wrong, but if it's wrong then there's something weird going on with your data and/or data structures, unless maybe you've simplified your example to remove irrelevant joins etc.

Comment: So I finally got out of that meeting and had a chance to look at this. That's definitely the answer to the question I asked, although its a different premise than I was thinking. I *think* I can make my code work better using this, although it'll be a little complicated. (the select statements for customer type 1 and 2 is actually from several tables and needs a few joins but I think this will execute faster if I do it like this).